Theme attributes do not work in Android Vector Drawables
My Themes color attributes do not work in Android Vector Drawables.
Providing two examples below:
android:fillColor declared with an @color
<!-- More vector source here -->
  <path
      android:pathData="M2.736,0L20.056,0A2.736,2.736 0,0 1,22.792 2.736L22.792,30.422A2.736,2.736 0,0 1,20.056 33.158L2.736,33.158A2.736,2.736 0,0 1,0 30.422L0,2.736A2.736,2.736 0,0 1,2.736 0z"
      android:strokeWidth="0.264583"
      android:fillColor="@color/blue_500"/>
<!-- More vector source here -->

Preview in Android Studio:

In app:

As you can notice the Vector Drawable displays correctly.
android:fillColor declared with an ?attr
<!-- More vector source here -->
  <path
      android:pathData="M2.736,0L20.056,0A2.736,2.736 0,0 1,22.792 2.736L22.792,30.422A2.736,2.736 0,0 1,20.056 33.158L2.736,33.158A2.736,2.736 0,0 1,0 30.422L0,2.736A2.736,2.736 0,0 1,2.736 0z"
      android:strokeWidth="0.264583"
      android:fillColor="?attr/colorTertiary"/>
<!-- More vector source here -->

Preview in Android Studio:

In app:

As you can notice the expected tertiary color is transparent and shows a view below it (Range Slider track if that is of any help)

I have read:

Theme attributes not working correctly with VectorDrawable
Android Studio 4.1: theme attributes in vector drawables cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
https://medium.com/makingtuenti/managing-your-android-app-iconography-a2f4aa9cb49d

None of these posts were helpful in resolution of this issue.
What can I do to resolve this unexpected behavior?
